# Redux Toolkit Entity Adapter - Selector not working even if my data is in {{entities},[ids]} format

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, redux-toolkit

Here is my data fetch-

```
const API_URI = "/fakeApi";

const fakeAPI = {
    employees: {
    async fetchAll() {
      const result = await fetch(`${API_URI}/employees`, { method: "GET" });
      return result.json();
    },
   }
};

export default fakeAPI;
```

Here is my slice data:

```
export const fetchEmployees = createAsyncThunk('employees/getEmployees', async () => {

    const result = await fakeAPI.employees.fetchAll();
    return result;

});

export const mangEmpCRUDSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'mangEmpCRUD',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      removeUser: employeeAdapter.removeOne
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
      builder.addCase(fetchEmployees.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
      });
      builder.addCase(fetchEmployees.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        employeeAdapter.upsertMany(state, action.payload.employees);
        state.loading = false;
      });
    }
});

export default mangEmpCRUDSlice.reducer;

export const { removeUser } = mangEmpCRUDSlice.actions;

export const {
  selectById: selectUserById,
  selectIds: selectUserIds,
  selectEntities: selectUserEntities,
  selectAll: selectAllUsers,
  selectTotal: selectTotalUsers
} = employeeAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.employees);
```

When I use SelectAllUser selector in my component, it gives me a type error even though my redux dev tools show that data fetched is in the format {{entities},[ids]}. PS: Using normalizer for my data is not fetching data in the format required by entity adapter.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible demo?  Like a CodeSandbox?

Comment: Here is the codesandbox   https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-entities-basic-example-forked-2ktid?file=/src/features/users/UsersList.js

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible that your api (fakeAPI) when it call result.json(), you're getting back another Promise, try using await result.json()